# Running native library downloaded from internet

Tags: android, android-ndk

I posted this question previously on G+ Android community, but no answer so far.
It's about downloading and loading native libraries.

I've been reading around and what I learned it that, it is in theory possible to download a ".so" file, and load it from using System.load method.

But I also read the following here (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/0uY4qgam1Ws) : "Also you should not be able to load an .so off the SDCARD on an ARM system by normal means, as ARM supports non-executable pages and android's implementation of mmap() refuses to map executable pages backed by a noexec file system."

It is a bit confusing for me to fair (a lot confusing actually).

So here is my question : is it or is it not possible, on a production device, to download a library, stick it somewhere on the phone, and load it then use it with JNI.

And if so, are we sure that it will still work in the future with new versions of Android?

Like, what is the official recommandation of Google about this?

Comment: Have you succeed in downloading the android vision native library and loading it in the application.

Comment: I don't really remember, it was too long ago, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this works on production devices. But it doesn't work on all devices if you put it in /sdcard, you should use the app private/internal folders (that correspond to /data/data/com.example.app/something) for this. You might need to do the equivalent of chmod +x on the file after creating/downloading it though.

I'm not sure if there's any official Google recommendations about it though, but the post you linked pretty clearly indicates that this is intended to work and there's no plans to break it.

Comment: I guess, but in the link I posted, Diane Hackborn, who works at Google for Android, seems pretty unsecured about her own answers so...

Comment: No, the unsure comment (her second reply in that thread) was about using the fennec binary loader, which she thought might rely on private subtle implementation details. Her first reply in the thread didn't show any such hesitation.

Comment: If I copy the .so file to the Context.getDir("lib", MODE_PRIVATE) path, then no need for a chmod +x. Also, it actually gives an alias, "/data/data/<myapp>/app_lib" instead of "/data/data/<myapp>/lib". Tested on several devices, ranging from Android 10 to 19, armeabi-v7a, x86...