# Android: load a shared library (.so) from the Internet

Tags: android, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

Is there possible to download *.so from the Internet (from my own server) and then  load it? I found questions like [Running native library downloaded from internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764458/running-native-library-downloaded-from-internet) but if maybe there is there way to download library into some kind of private zone and then load it?
And this approach should work on all new devices without any additional manipulations, such as getting root.

Comment: @lewkka No,  Android library and shared (native) library - different things.

Comment: Answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582717/android-can-write-to-lib-dir